# Error: Could not find or load main class .usr.local.pig-0.16.0 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: /usr/local/pig-0/16/0

Tags: macos, hadoop, installation, apache-pig

I am trying to installing PIG in my MACOS but after extraction of tar file when i execute pig command on my terminal i get classnotfound exception

```
Error: Could not find or load main class .usr.local.pig-0.16.0
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: /usr/local/pig-0/16/0
```

[image]

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.4.jdk/Contents/Home
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$JAVA_HOME/lib

export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop-2.7.5   
export HADOOP_INSTALL=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_PREFIX=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_HOME/lib"  
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export PATH=.:$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/bin:$HADOOP_INSTALL/sbin
export CLASSPATH=.:$CLASSPATH:$HADOOP_HOME/lib:$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/common

export PIG_OPTS=/usr/local/pig-0.16.0
export PIG_HOME=/usr/local/pig-0.16.0
export PIG_CONF_DIR=$PIG_HOME/conf   
export PIG_CLASSPATH=$PIG_CONF_DIR
export PATH=$PATH:$PIG_HOME/bin
```

Comment: I don't think Pig or Hadoop supports Java 9

Comment: Try removing `PIG_OPTS=/usr/local/pig-0.16.0`